# question regarding polyhedra in algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

This picture is taken from algebraic topology  by Rotman. I have two question regarding this section.
(1) How to prove Real projective plane is a polyhedra. Although they have said it will lead to polyhedra but didn't give any solution for it.

(2) Most Importantly how can I prove excercise 7.1, I have been seeing many people posting the solution although assume $RP^2$ is obtained after identifying  antipodal points of $S^2$, although I dont know how to prove that either. So it will be great if you can provide me a proof or a hint of the question.

Comment: The real projective plain is not a polyhedra, in any sense that I can think of. I suppose it can be triangulated.

Comment: although I believe its written it can lead to polyhedra

Comment: What is the definition of “polyhedra” you are using.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews There seems to be a specialised definition of polyhedra in algebraic topology.

Comment: A topolgical space X is polyhedron if there exists a simplical complex $K$ and a homemorphism from h:$|K| \rightarrow X$.

Comment: Yes, that is why I’m asking. What is it? @Milten

Comment: And then also the question 7.1 can be proven

Comment: It is one 'polyhedron', many 'polyhedra'. Let $\mathbb{R}P^2=S^2/[z\sim -z]$. The inclusion $S^2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ induces a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}P^2\cong (\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})/(z\sim -z)$. Write $D^2=S^1\times I/(S^1\times 0)$ and define $\Phi:D^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ by $\Phi((x,y),t)=[t\cdot x,t\cdot y,\sqrt{1-t^2}]$. This gives you Ex. 7.1.

Comment: How are you establishing homeomorphism between $S^2$ and $RP^2$. As I have mentioned in the question that I dont know that and is there any other ways to do it rather than establishing this homeomorphism

Comment: @amathlover Which definition of real projective space are you familiar with (you may want to include that in your post)? (I guess it is " the straight lines passing thourgh the orgin in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$")

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Rotman defines a polyhedron as a trianguable space.

Comment: @Tyrone Rotman defines $\mathbb RP^2$ as the space obtained from Fig. (i) by identifying the edges as depicted.

Comment: @Kevin.S See my above comment.

Comment: @PaulFrost OK, then the homeomorphism is induced by deforming the square to a disk and composing pairs of adjacent edges.

Comment: @Kevin.S The given definition in the picture is the definition I know of Real projective plane. I am reading it for the first time

Comment: @amathlover Ok. *Hint:* First, do you see that $\Bbb{RP}^2$ is homeomorphic to a disk with every $1/4$ of its boundary labelled? Second, could you compose the two pairs of adjacent arcs to obtained a new arc. Third, after composing, do you see that every point on the boundary of the disk is identified with it antipodal point? (If you still have problems, please tell me, and I'll try to organize everything in an answer.)

Comment: @Kevin.S it will be great if you can put it in an answer

Comment: @amathlover Just posted.

Comment: @amathlover Look at the map I wrote down. You know $D^2\cong I^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post them here because the OP requested an answer.

> 1. Is it a polyhedron?

Yes, by Paul Frost's comment below the post (I don't have Rotman's book)

to see this, you could split the rectangle into 9 retangular regions and subdivide each region into two triangles by joining the two long diagnal lines and two "medium-sized" diagnal lines, which would give a valid triangulation.

(just corrected a terrible error: Only one diagnal line doesn't work because the image of each simplex won't be spanned by three vertices, after identification)

> 2. Prove $X=I^2/{\sim}=[-1,1]^2/{\sim}=\Bbb{RP}^2$ is homeomorphic to $D^2/{x\sim-x}$ for $x\in\partial D^2\approx S^1$.

For the current boundary of the representation of $\Bbb{RP}^2$, we can see that it is homeomorphic to $S^1/{\sim}$ by $f:\partial X\to \partial D^2/{\sim}, (x',y')\mapsto\frac{(x',y')}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}$ because it is a continuous bijection from a compact space to a hausdorff space, where $\partial X$ refers to the boundary of the square representation of $\Bbb{RP}^2$. Therefore $f^{-1}$, without explicitly writing it out, is also a homeomorphism.

Define $h:D^2/{\sim}\to X$, an extension of $f^{-1}$ to the interior of the disk:
$$
h(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
(0,0) & (x,y)=(0,0)\\
\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}(x,y) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
It is clearly bijective, and it's continuous on the second branch. To verify the continuity at $(0,0)$, consider $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}(x,y)=(0,0)$. Thus, the first branch is a continuous extension of the second which implies $h$'s continuity. Because $h$ is a continuous bijection from a compact space to a hausdorff space and is equivalence relation preserving, it's a homeomorphism.

A simple remark: I didn't combine the two branches is because $\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}=||f^{-1}(\frac{(x',y')}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}})||$, which is undefined at $(0,0)$, so we have to prove the continuity of the extension just like what we did in the preceding paragraph.

**Edit:**

To visualize this homeomorphism, I found that this picture from Munkres's Topology might work as well:

[image]

Now, you could easily see that any point on the boundary of the 2-disk is identified with its antipodal point by the labelling scheme.

To check that the equivalence classes are preserved, we can do the following:

In $X$, $(x,-1)\sim(-x,1)$, $f(x,-1)$ ends up with an arc on the unit circle by $f:(x',y')\mapsto\frac{(x',y')}{||(x',y')||}$. Now, by direct calculation, $f(x,-1)$ lies between $(-\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$ and $(\sqrt{2}/2,-\sqrt{2}/2)$, which can be represented as $$f(x,-1)=(\cos([\dfrac{5}{4}\pi,\dfrac{7}{5}\pi]),\sin([\dfrac{5}{4}\pi,\dfrac{7}{4}\pi]))$$
$f(-x,1)$ lies between $f(-1,1)=(-\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$ and $f(1,1)=(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$, which can be represented as $$(\cos([\dfrac{1}{4}\pi,\dfrac{3}{5}\pi]),\sin([\dfrac{1}{4}\pi,\dfrac{3}{4}\pi]))=(\cos([\dfrac{5}{4}\pi-\pi,\dfrac{7}{5}\pi-\pi]),\sin([\dfrac{5}{4}\pi-\pi,\dfrac{7}{4}\pi-\pi]))$$
Here, trigonometry tells us that they're pairs of antipodal points. A similar argument shows that the same thing happens on $(-1,y)\sim(1,-y)$. $h$ also satisfies this because $h|_{\partial D^2}=f^{-1}$, which sends everything back by a continuous bijection.

---

Any question please feel free to ask.

Comment: How do you know $f$ is getting quotientize, can you tell me about that

Comment: @amathlover the point is that we remember the equivalence relation but don't identify them, so that those point, remaining the equivalence relation assigned to them, still maintain the geometric properties , (e.g. the boundary can still be regarded as a circle), so $f$ is valid.

Comment: @amathlover Also, $f$ itself is not getting quotienized but the domain and range are two quotient spaces because the point contained in them are assigned equivalence relations.  I wrote them that way just to remind me that the equivalence relation is not manipulated.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, the map is going from quotient space of $\delta(I\times I)$ to $S^1$. Now to show this map is passing through quotient space of  $I \times I$, you have to show the identification points are being mapped to the same point in $S^1$, which is not happening over here

Comment: @amathlover Well, if I get what you meant correctly, you want to show that the equivalence classes are identified to a single point in the resulting space, right? But notice, we can represent a quotient space by labelling those equivalence classes instead of gluing them together. However, if you want me to show that the equivalence classes on the boundary of the square is indeed mapped to the a pair of antipodal points, I can do that.

Comment: Yes yes it will be great if you can do it

Comment: Ok, I just finished editing it. @amathlover

Comment: Here is Rotman's definition: A topological space $X$ is a polyhedron if there exists a simplicial complex $K$ and a homemorphism $h: \lvert K \rvert \to X$. The ordered pair $(K, h)$ is called a triangulation of $X$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you, I just realized that what I did before doesn't work..